# Appending a submit handler to user_pass_submit to enable form redirect after submission

Tags: 7, forms, hooks

If I understand correctly, having

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'my_extra_submit';
```

in a `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter` would execute `my_extra_submit` *after* it executes the default handler.

However, running my code through a debugger, I see that in the array `$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'` there is only one element, and thats `my_extra_submit`. Thus after I press the `Email New Password` button, it only executes the code that is in `my_extra_submit`.

That wasn't the result I'm trying to achieve. I wanted to run the normal submit handler: `user_pass_submit` and *then* run `my_extra_submit`.

The reason for this is I want to redirect the user to a custom page after it finishes submission.

So use case:

- user goes to /user/password
- enters email
- presses `email new password`
- password is emailed
- user is redirected to `node/1` with a `drupal_set_message("Please check your mail")`

But currently whats happening is:

- user goes to /user/password
- enters email
- presses `email new password`
- password is *NOT* emailed
- user is redirected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have a look in $form['#submit'] and try to add you submit handler there $form['#submit'][] = 'my_extra_submit'

Comment: I had come back to answer my question but see that Pontus had already pointed it out.

The solution was 

    $form['#submit'][] = 'my_extra_submit';

instead of

    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'my_extra_submit';

Now everything works like it should!